# XSLT: use parameters in xls:sort attributes (dynamic sorting)

Tags: php, xslt, sorting, parameters

How do I apply a parameter to a `select` and `order` attribute in a `xsl:sort` element? I'ld like to do this dynamic with PHP with something like this:

```
$xsl = new XSLTProcessor();
$xslDoc = new DOMDocument(); 
$xslDoc->load( $this->_xslFilePath );
$xsl->importStyleSheet( $xslDoc );
$xsl->setParameter( '', 'sortBy', 'viewCount' );
$xsl->setParameter( '', 'order', 'descending' );
```

But I'ld first have to now how to get this to work. I tried the following, but it gives me a 'compilation error' : 'invalid value $order for order'. `$sortBy` doesn't seem to do anything either:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:param name="sortBy" select="viewCount"/>
<xsl:param name="order" select="descending"/>
<xsl:template match="/">
    <media>
    <xsl:for-each select="media/medium">
    <xsl:sort select="$sortBy" order="$order"/>
        // <someoutput>
    </xsl:for-each>
    </media>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**You are close to the correct solution**, but there are a few issues:

1. `<xsl:param name="sortBy" select="viewCount"/>`
   This defines the `$sortBy` parameter as the value of the `viewCount` child of the current node (the document node). Because the top element is not named `viewCount`, the `$sortBy` parameter so defined has no value at all.
2. `<xsl:param name="order" select="descending"/>` 
   Ditto.
3. `<xsl:sort select="$sortBy" order="$order"/>`
   Even if issues 1. and 2. above are fixed, this xslt instruction is still problematic. It specifies the value of the `order` attribute as the literal string `'$order'` -- not as the value of the parameter `$order`. The way to do this in XSLT is by using AVT (Attribute Value Template). Whenever we want a to specify that within an attribute value we want a particular string to be evaluated as an XPath expression, then this string must be surrounded by curly braces.

So, the `order` attribute should be specified as: `order = '{$order}'`.

Unfortunately, AVTs cannot be used for the `select` attribute (another rule from the XSLT spec).

The way to specify the value of the `select` attribute is a little-bit more tricky:

`select='*[name()=$sortBy]'`  This says: sort by the child element, whose name is the same as the value of the variable `$sortBy`.

**To put all this together, here is the corrected transformation**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:param name="sortBy" select="'viewCount'"/>
 <xsl:param name="order" select="'descending'"/>

 <xsl:template match="/">
    <media>
      <xsl:for-each select="media/medium">
        <xsl:sort select="*[name()=$sortBy]" order="{$order}"/>

        <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </media>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When this transformation is applied on the following XML document**:

```
<media>
 <medium>
   <viewCount>2</viewCount>
 </medium>
 <medium>
   <viewCount>1</viewCount>
 </medium>
 <medium>
   <viewCount>5</viewCount>
 </medium>
</media>
```

**The correct result is produced**:

```
<media>
   <medium>
      <viewCount>5</viewCount>
   </medium>
   <medium>
      <viewCount>2</viewCount>
   </medium>
   <medium>
      <viewCount>1</viewCount>
   </medium>
</media>
```

Comment: +1 Thank you so much for the extended explanation. That is brilliant. This works perfectly! And now it makes sense. I've been banging my head against the wall these last couple of hours. Thank you.

Comment: Dimitre- This is an excellent answer saved me a lot of time. I have a question can I pass a string  to my local variable a an xpath expression then so that this localvariable will be used on for-each select=$myLocalVar to loop through.  .setParameters(null,filter,"*/person[contains(name,'John')]