# XSLT sorting:both ascending and descending

Tags: sharepoint, xslt

i have a sharepoint list column which has number datatype ..whenever the user sorts them ascending or descending i should get it as they were..but xslt sorting allows either ascending or descending..how can i make it flexible?..could anyone please help me with this

Comment: In case this is not another Sharepoint specific question, take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2529465/xslt-use-parameters-in-xlssort-attributes-dynamic-sorting

Answer (score 0):

you can use conditional formating

```
<xsl:choose>
<xsl:when test="$sortorder='Asc'>
<xsl:call-template name="asctemplate" />
</xsl:when>
<xsl:when test="$sortorder='Desc'>
<xsl:call-template name="desctemplate" />
</xsl:when>
</xsl:choose>
```