# Dynamic XSLT sorting

Tags: php, xml, xslt, sorting

My issue is very similar to this one:

[XSLT: use parameters in xls:sort attributes (dynamic sorting)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2529465/xslt-use-parameters-in-xlssort-attributes-dynamic-sorting)

But I'd like to sort it by node's attribute.
How to change this command:

```
<xsl:sort select="*[name()=$sortBy]" order="{$order}"/>
```

so that instead of name() function, there would be comparison to names of attributes?
Or is there any other way to (dynamically according to given parameter) sort nodes by their attributes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `<xsl:sort select="@*[name()=$sortBy]" order="{$order}"/>`, that is all that is needed.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I didn't expect such an easy solution of such a complicated language! :)